# Infering "internal" type using TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a type definition for a OSS JS project, and have the need to infer an "internal" type in a type alias.

There's a certain type that can be either:

```
ActionFunc<State, Payload> = (state: State, payload: Payload) => State
```

Which takes a payload from a given event directly. If you want to combine both the payload state with your own local data into a *different* payload type, you can instead use:

```
[ActionFunc<State, ??>, (data: Payload) => ?]
```

Which is a tuple containing an `AnctionFunc` over the same state, but with a *different* payload parameter, which can be *generated* by first applying the second tuple item to map from the normal `Payload` type to the custom one.

The *naive* version of this type alias would be something like:

```
type Action<State, StandardPayload = {}, CustomPayload = void> =
    | ActionFunc<State, StandardPayload>
    | [ActionFunc<State, CustomPayload>, (payload: StandardPayload) => CustomPayload]
```

*But* the problem I have is this exposes the `CustomPayload` parameter "externally", when theoretically it should be possible to *infer* it and use it internally consistently, e.g.:

```
type Action<State, StandardPayload = {}> =
    | ActionFunc<State, StandardPayload>
    | [ActionFunc<State, infer CustomPayload>, (payload: StandardPayload) => CustomPayload]
```

And as long as the parameter types for the `ActionFunc` and the `payload composer` function *match* we don't care what that type is as a consumer/caller.

Current TS only allows `infer` in the context of an `extends` conditional type, but I can't figure out what condition actually make sense here.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "exposing it externally"... Can you elaborate?

Comment: Types need to be able to contain references to an `Action<??>` that are "open" to whatever arbitrary custom types consumers of that type need, .e.g. `interface Item<State> { onFoo?: Action<State, FooPayload>; onBar?: Action<State, BarPayload> }` and can invoke/dispatch the action without concern for whatever custom type might be used "internally" on each callback action.

Comment: I could "get around this" with using "any" for the custom payload type, but that wouldn't help catch consumers from providing incorrectly typed "payload mapper" functions in the second item in the tuple. It should be "internally consistent" but doesn't need to be exposed to consumers of the actions.

Answer (score 2):

You want [existentially quantified generic types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), which are [not directly implemented in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) (or most other languages with generics either, for what it's worth.  Even Haskell only [supports them](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type) if you enable a language extension for [higher rank types](https://wiki.haskell.org/Rank-N_types).)  TypeScript only has *universally* quantified generic types; an implementation/definition of a universally quantified generic type like `Foo<T>` needs to be able to handle any possible value of `T` that the caller/user of the type wants.  An existential type inverts this: the *caller/user* of an existentially qualified generic type like (made-up-syntax) `exists T. Foo<T>` needs to be able to handle any possible value of `T` that the *implementation/definition* wants.  From the caller's point of view, all you can specify is that `T` will correspond to *some* type (existential), not *any* type (universal).

So what can we do in TypeScript without direct support for existentials?  Well, we can get indirect support by inverting control with functions and callbacks, which essentially flips universals to existentials and vice versa.  Think of it as dealing with something like a promise instead of a value itself:

```
type ActionPair<S, P, C> = [ActionFunc<S, P>, (payload: P) => C];

type ActionPairPromise<S, P> = {
  then<R>(onfulfilled: <C>(value: ActionPair<S, P, C>) => R): R;
};
```

This hides the `C` parameter, but in order to use it you will have to pass callbacks all over the place:

```
// turn a concrete ActionPair<S, P, C> into the existential ActionPairPromise<S, P>
function actionPairToActionPairPromise<S, P, C>(
  actionPair: ActionPair<S, P, C>
): ActionPairPromise<S, P> {
  return {
    then(onfulfilled) {
      return onfulfilled(actionPair);
    }
  };
}

// take the existential ActionPairPromise<S, P> and do something with it
// namely, convert into an ActionFunc
function actionPairPromiseToActionFunc<S, P>(
  value: ActionPairPromise<S, P>
): ActionFunc<S, P> {
  return value.then(actionPair => (state: S, payload: P) =>
    actionPair[0](state, actionPair[1](payload))
  );
}
```

There are other ways to proceed in lieu of existentials... you can use `any` as you said and then make all functions that accept such types generic and do an extra check to make sure that it conforms to some `C` parameter...

But I strongly suspect here that when it comes down to it, the only thing you are going to be able to *do* with an `ActionPairPromise<S, P>` is to convert it into an `ActionFunc<S, P>`.  So why not just do that?

```
type ActionFunc<State, Payload> = (state: State, payload: Payload) => State;
type Action<State, StandardPayload = {}> = ActionFunc<State, StandardPayload>;

type ActionPair<S, P, C> = [ActionFunc<S, C>, (payload: P) => C];

function convertYourActionToUsefulAction<S, P, C>(
  action: Action<S, P> | ActionPair<S, P, C>
): Action<S, P> {
  if (Array.isArray(action)) {
    return (state: S, payload: P) => action[0](state, action[1](payload));
  } else {
    return action;
  }
}
```

That is, the only place you use that type is in the function that converts to a normal `ActionFunc` and be done with it.

Anyway, hope that helps give you some ideas.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response! The complicating part of this, is the fact that this is actually just for a type declaration for an existing JS library that handles this, so I don't have any say on the *implementation*, I'm only trying to get a reasonable type system on top of the existing behaviour.

Comment: If you can't change the library and don't feel like wrapping the library with more straightforwardly-typed interfaces, then you'll probably have to keep your "exposed" `Action<S, P, C>` type and make everything that deals with them generic in `C`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not sure how to do that when you have N properties on a type that are `Action`s so you have to parameterize the type that many times. Ugh.

Comment: I guess it depends on what `N` is.  Are you *required* to support `ActionPair` for your use cases?   It's fine for the library to support it but for you to ignore it in favor of a more straightforward typing.  And if you do use that functionality somewhere you can call `convertYourActionToUsefulAction()` first.  If your use case is something like "make typings for every piece of this external library without modifying any of its functionality or wrapping it in any way and also without having to talk about these internal types" then I'd say you're going to be unhappy.

Comment: Yeah, the primary goal is to accurately provide a type declaration for the stock library as is, that is as type safe as possible, given the current options in TypeScript. An additional library that builds on the stock library is a secondary goal. Thanks for the insights!